# Error Resolving Cookbooks for runlist: missing cookbooks: No such Cookbook 'docker'

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, cookbook

I am trying to run this

`Berksfile`:

```rb
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'
metadata
```

`metadata.rb`:

```rb
name 'my_jenkins_cookbook'

depends 'git'
depends 'ruby_rbenv'
depends 'jenkins'
depends 'java'
depends 'docker'

version '0.0.2'
```

I have also tried will the required cookbooks in local and it doesn't locate `jenkins_job` resource from the `jenkins_job` cookbook.

Can someone help me with this blockage please?

[image: Image - is the error]

TERMINAL OUTPUT:

```
 [DEBUG] Running command 4-run-chef-solo
 [DEBUG] No test for command 4-run-chef-solo
 [ERROR] Command 4-run-chef-solo (chef-solo -c /tmp/chef/solo.rb -j /tmp/chef/jenkins.json) failed
 [DEBUG] Command 4-run-chef-solo output: Starting Chef Infra Client, version 17.0.242
Patents: https://www.chef.io/patents
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["my_jenkins_cookbook::jenkins_jobs", "my_jenkins_cookbook::jenkins_views", "my_jenkins_cookbook::setup_jenkins_users"]

============================================================
Error Resolving Cookbooks for Run List:
============================================================

Missing Cookbooks:
------------------
No such cookbook: docker

Expanded Run List:
------------------
* my_jenkins_cookbook::jenkins_jobs
* my_jenkins_cookbook::jenkins_views
* my_jenkins_cookbook::setup_jenkins_users

System Info:
------------
chef_version=17.0.242
platform=ubuntu
platform_version=18.04
ruby=ruby 3.0.1p64 (2021-04-05 revision 0fb782ee38) [x86_64-linux]
program_name=/usr/bin/chef-solo
executable=/opt/chef/bin/chef-solo

Running handlers:
 ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
 ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Infra Client failed. 0 resources updated in 26 seconds
 FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/chef/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
 FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
 FATAL: Net::HTTPServerException: 412 "Precondition Failed"
```

Comment: share a terminal output as a text snippet and not as an image to be able to read it and help you

Comment: Hi @Mr.

Thank you for your reply. I just added the terminal output.

Comment: Try the chef slack channel https://community-slack.chef.io/ they are pretty helpful

Answer (score 0):

how are you running this? Is this straight on a node with chef-client or through Test Kitchen?

It looks to me, like you're running chef-solo directly, but the cookbooks haven't been loaded onto the server.

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue

Looks like the `chef-solo` execution **could not find the dependent cookbooks**, as indicated in the error log. So here is the alternative approach to solve the issue.

#### Resolution

Alternative suggestion for `chef-solo` is to run `chef-client` using `-z` option.

Chef client version 11 and above having an option called `chef-client -z`. It is called Chef client execution in `local mode`.

It is the suggested way to run cookbooks without Chef server.

Chef documentation for Chef-client states the below,

```
$ chef-client OPTION VALUE OPTION VALUE ...

-z, --local-mode
Run the chef-client in local mode. This allows all commands that work against the Chef server to also work against the local chef-repo.
```

> Local mode does not require a configuration file, instead it will look
> for a directory named `/cookbooks` and will set `chef_repo_path` to be
> just above that. (Local mode will honor the settings in a
> configuration file, if desired.)
>
> Local mode will store temporary and cache files under the
> `<chef_repo_path>/.cache` directory by default. This allows a normal
> user to run the chef-client in local mode without requiring root
> access.

So please follow the instructions below,

- You need to create a project repository with your cookbooks and other stuff.
- Project repo is nothing but a directory containing other directories for Roles, Databags, Cookbooks and Environments
- Create a directory called `cookbooks` in the project repo
- *Since you already have the `Berksfile` in your cookbooks, run `berks vendor cookbooks` command from the each cookbook directory to pull all your dependent cookbooks and store it in the `cookbooks` directory*
- Run the below command from the project repo to invoke the Chef client in local mode.

`chef-client -z -o 'provide_your_overridden_runlist'`

- This steps needs to be executed in the Jenkins script section

Read more in Chef Docs,

- [Chef client run in local mode](https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_client/#run-in-local-mode)
- [Berks Vendor CLI command](https://docs.chef.io/workstation/berkshelf/#berks-vendor)